# Set separatorStyle for a table view, but on Storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

In code you can

```
tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

However,  (1) on Storyboard I experimented with using User Defined Runtime Attributes.  In fact, this

[image]

works well to get rid of the separators.  But it would be better to somehow use the constant, `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None` rather than guess a zero. Is there a way?

Also (2) Is it in fact correct that on the **Attributes Inspector**, for UITableView, there is no way to turn off separators?

(As a further curiosity, for me the Separator Inset control simply does not work, it changes nothing on the separators.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alway set separator from storyboard as well as from xibs. Here's how you can do it.

[image: separator] [image]

Comment: Always Happy to help. :)